# MySQL: Why does inserting in table A block updates to table B?

Tags: mysql

We've identified a strange situation in our production database.

It goes approximately like this:

Process A does the following:

```
set transaction isolation level read committed;
start transaction;
    -- 500K records, takes over a minute
    insert into tableA (f1, f2, f3) select f1, f2, f3 from tempTableB; 
commit;
```

Process B meanwhile does:

```
update tableC set f=f+10 where id=1234;
```

Tables `tableA` and `tableC` are completely unrelated (and `tempTableB` is a temporary able exclusive to the first process). However while the insert into `tableA` is in progress, the update to `tableC` gets stuck waiting. For what? No idea.

Read queries meanwhile are processing just fine and quickly.

A few other details which are perhaps relevant. Feel free to ask for more:

- The DB is hosted, but fairly beefy - 8 vCPUs, 32GB RAM, SSD storage. It's not buckling under the load.
- MySQL version is 8.0.21
- There is replication set up for High Availability
- Neither of these tables have any triggers, and there aren't any foreign keys between them either
- They are both InnoDB tables.

What's going on here? Why does an insert into one table block updates to another completely unrelated table?

Comment: Are there any triggers?

Comment: Please post results for `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` while the log occurs

Comment: I wonder if you might have some oddly configured setting related to concurrency, such as `innodb_thread_concurrency`, limiting the number of concurrent threads on your writer, outside of the sql scope.  Probably unlikely, but maybe something to check if you find nothing else.

Comment: @Stu No, no triggers anywhere.

Comment: @Asgar - At the moment I don't have any more of these long queries planned, but they do happen fairly frequently (according to business needs). The next time this happens I'll remember to take a look at the `show engine innodb status`.

Comment: @AldenW. - No idea. I think it would be more obvious then? Anyways, `innodb_thread_concurrency` is `0`.

Comment: Consider running SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; while your second task is apparently blocked.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Hm? We've got that. There's a monitoring process that checks every few seconds for all queries that have been running too long. That's how we discovered that the first query was blocking over 50 other queries. But I already figured it out, see below.

Comment: Thanks for posting your research and conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself. I'll leave it here for posterity, maybe someone else has a similar situation. The devil was in a few more details that I left out thinking them as irrelevant...

Here's a bit less simplified version of the whole process A script:

```
set transaction isolation level read committed;

create temporary table tempTableB ...;

-- 500K records, takes nearly 5 minutes, but does not block anything.
-- tableD is actively used (inserted/updated) all this time
insert into tempTableB (f1, f2, f3) select f1, f2, f3 from tableD where ...;

start transaction;
    -- 500K records, takes over a minute
    insert into tableA (f1, f2, f3) select f1, f2, f3 from tempTableB join tableE on tempTableB.f1=tableE.id;
commit;
```

Can you spot it?

Probably not, because there's one more invisible piece to this puzzle: the default transaction isolation level, which is `repeatable read`.

Armed with this knowledge now we can put it all together:

1. The `set transaction isolation level read committed;` does not specify either `session` or `global`, so MySQL defaults to "[just the next statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html#set-transaction-scope)". This is the `insert into tempTableB...`, which indeed works marvelously. 5 minutes of execution, yet nothing and nobody notices that. Perfect.
2. After that is completed, the transaction isolation level drops back to `repeatable read`;
3. Now comes `insert into tableA ... select from tempTableB join tableC`. Since this is now **NOT** `read committed`, MySQL [starts setting locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) onto `tableC` records that it touches. Indeed, all the blocking writes were to `tableC` only. All other tables worked just fine.

The solution, of course, is simple: change the very first line to

```
set session transaction isolation level read committed;
```

Comment: It would have been helpful  to show in your original question that the `INSERT into TableA SELECT...` referenced `TableC` as well.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Yeah....